# INTEL CPU turbo boost pegged at its clock-speed sometimes

Tags: 12.04, turbo-boost

I have a ubuntu 12.04 LTS server running at 2 INTEL xeon E5-2620v2 processors.

At busy time the turbo boost will work: (monitor with turbostat I get:)

```
pk cor CPU    %c0  GHz  TSC SMI    %c1    %c3    %c6    %c7 CTMP PTMP   %pc2   %pc3   %pc6   %pc7  Pkg_W  Cor_W RAM_W PKG_% RAM_%

            86.04 2.25 2.10   0  13.00   0.18   0.78   0.00   65   65   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  70.16  44.67 12.27  0.00  0.00

 0   0   0  90.06 2.40 2.10   0   9.94   0.00   0.00   0.00   61   62   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  37.60  24.81  6.65  0.00  0.00

 0   0  12  95.81 2.40 2.10   0   4.19

 0   1   1  86.58 2.40 2.10   0  12.77   0.16   0.49   0.00   58

 0   1  13  84.33 2.40 2.10   0  15.02

 0   2   2  86.17 2.40 2.10   0  12.91   0.21   0.70   0.00   57

 0   2  14  82.83 2.40 2.10   0  16.25

 0   3   3  86.54 2.40 2.10   0  12.35   0.14   0.97   0.00   62

 0   3  15  85.89 2.40 2.10   0  13.00

 0   4   4  84.26 2.40 2.10   0  14.97   0.31   0.47   0.00   62

 0   4  16  85.31 2.40 2.10   0  13.91

 0   5   5  85.75 2.40 2.10   0  13.36   0.10   0.79   0.00   55

 0   5  17  84.65 2.40 2.10   0  14.46

 1   0   6  85.73 2.10 2.10   0  13.14   0.25   0.87   0.00   64   65   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  32.55  19.86  5.62  0.00  0.00

 1   0  18  84.96 2.10 2.10   0  13.91

 1   1   7  85.13 2.10 2.10   0  13.67   0.24   0.96   0.00   65

 1   1  19  85.62 2.10 2.10   0  13.18

 1   2   8  86.23 2.10 2.10   0  12.22   0.30   1.25   0.00   63

 1   2  20  85.05 2.10 2.10   0  13.40

 1   3   9  87.43 2.10 2.10   0  11.46   0.14   0.97   0.00   60

 1   3  21  84.09 2.10 2.10   0  14.80

 1   4  10  84.61 2.10 2.10   0  14.19   0.13   1.07   0.00   58

 1   4  22  86.24 2.10 2.10   0  12.55

 1   5  11  84.93 2.10 2.10   0  14.11   0.16   0.80   0.00   60

 1   5  23  86.67 2.10 2.10   0  12.37

As you can see the pkg 0 all 12 cpus turbo frequency to 2.4G. 


But I also find at busy time cpu pegged and my application get worst performance.

pk cor CPU    %c0  GHz  TSC SMI    %c1    %c3    %c6    %c7 CTMP PTMP   %pc2   %pc3   %pc6   %pc7  Pkg_W  Cor_W RAM_W PKG_% RAM_%

            81.56 2.10 2.10   0  17.54   0.15   0.75   0.00   64   64   0.02   0.00  0.00   0.00  63.74  38.62 10.50  0.00  0.00

 0   0   0  88.05 2.10 2.10   0  11.95   0.00   0.00   0.00   56   57   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  32.16  19.50  6.24  0.00  0.00

 0   0  12  96.44 2.10 2.10   0   3.56

 0   1   1  82.42 2.10 2.10   0  16.89   0.15   0.55   0.00   54

 0   1  13  82.60 2.10 2.10   0  16.70

 0   2   2  84.48 2.10 2.10   0  15.04   0.11   0.37   0.00   51

 0   2  14  81.57 2.10 2.10   0  17.94

 0   3   3  83.53 2.10 2.10   0  15.61   0.13   0.72   0.00   54

 0   3  15  82.76 2.10 2.10   0  16.38

 0   4   4  84.55 2.10 2.10   0  14.80   0.12   0.53   0.00   57

 0   4  16  81.77 2.10 2.10   0  17.58

 0   5   5  82.58 2.10 2.10   0  16.97   0.03   0.41   0.00   51

 0   5  17  80.30 2.10 2.10   0  19.25

 1   0   6  77.37 2.10 2.10   0  21.37   0.30   0.96   0.00   60   64   0.03   0.00   0.00   0.00  31.58  19.12  4.26  0.00  0.00

 1   0  18  78.15 2.10 2.10   0  20.60

 1   1   7  78.57 2.10 2.10   0  20.11   0.21   1.11   0.00   64

 1   1  19  77.48 2.10 2.10   0  21.19

 1   2   8  80.80 2.10 2.10   0  17.75   0.20   1.26   0.00   60

 1   2  20  78.09 2.10 2.10   0  20.45

 1   3   9  77.46 2.10 2.10   0  21.31   0.27   0.97   0.00   57

 1   3  21  77.07 2.10 2.10   0  21.70

 1   4  10  81.03 2.10 2.10   0  17.64   0.13   1.20   0.00   57

 1   4  22  80.29 2.10 2.10   0  18.38

 1   5  11  81.34 2.10 2.10   0  17.56   0.17   0.93   0.00   59

 1   5  23  78.70 2.10 2.10   0  20.20
```

as you can see pkg 0 and 1 all 24 cpus pegged at 2.1G
At this time I do not noticed high temperature nor high Watt.

Are there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at specs:
http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5-2620%20v2.html
Turbo is:
2.6 all cores in action
2.4 if one core
2.2 nominal, same as TSC
Monitoring CPU works by sampling counters, the shortest is the window, the more accurate are the values. This goes so fast that at time of reading, the tool may report last state. Thus, during reading, you can provide load to CPUs on 1, 2, ..., all cores and compare with idle state (no desktop)
You will have to pine one of your benchmark software to the selected core : recommend 'cpuset' and linpack.c

Perhaps you may also try my code. It has been however programmed with a Core i7 but using the cpuset command you may pined it to a Xeon package ID
Once started it will show you CPUs cycles through the fixed performance counters, and by the way frequencies, ratios (including Turbo), C-states %, temperatures and kernel task monitoring beside each Core threads. All of that with graphics
You can check which applications is guilty to burns your CPUs, or idle stage. 
Using [+] [-] buttons, you can decrease, increase, sleep time between each counters reading loop, down to 50000 usecs
Source code is available at http://code.google.com/p/xfreq/
Hope it will help you to investigate your issue